# In-room TV has a USB port, but the provided remote doesn't have buttons for it. Can I use a universal remote to solve the problem during my next trip?

Tags: electronic-items, sea-travel, cruising, entertainment

The TV looks like this on the 'Brilliance of the Seas' Royal Caribbean International ship:

[image: back of the TV on the Royal Caribbean Brilliance of the Seas]

But then the TV says this:
[image]

And there 's no "enter" on the remote.
[image]

Would it be wise to bring a universal remote next time so that I could hit enter (suggestions)?

I asked at reception and they said that the remote control only worked with the digital system, not the TV, so I was hosed.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

- Yes, I tried every possible button on the remote.  Nothing worked.  I also tried every possible button on the TV.  No luck there either.
- The model of the TV was Samsung Model UN26D4003BH, Type UN26D4003, made in Mexico in 2012.

Comment: There is an "Enter" button on that remote, just below 9.

Comment: Thanks vclaw, but that 'enter' apparently goes to the digital system, not the TV.  It certainly doesn't work.  Believe me, I tried for hours to get this to work.  I was on a 14 day cruise and had TONS of movies I brought, that I couldn't watch.  I pressed every possible button on the remote and every possible button on the TV.

Comment: That picture looks sort of like a universal remote. Maybe it can be put into "TV mode" and then one of the numerous buttons might function as Enter.

Comment: It's also possible that the TV does not have the capability of playing movies. The USB port may be for firmware updates to the TV. What's the TV brand and model?

Comment: Is it possible that the inputs are locked out?

Comment: OK is the enter and this TV plays photos but not videos

Comment: I've edited your post to make it more broad and travel-related.

Comment: Did you try "OK"?

Comment: @pnuts I'm pretty sure this is off topic at SU, they only entertain questions related to "normal" desktop computers. Smartphones, smart TVs, etc. are off-topic. It's a bit silly, because all these things **are** computers, and they can be "desktop" if you connect a keyboard and mouse. But that's how SU works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've owned/operated a few 'smart' TV sets and invariably their firmware sucked: the UI was horrible, the interface was slow, few formats were supported, built-in subtitles failed to load, etc. Therefore the only real solution is to take an HDMI-capable device in your luggage. This can be a [phone](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sFreeText=hdmi) with an HDMI port, a laptop, a tablet, or a separate '[TV Box](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=node%3D13447451&field-keywords=mkv%20&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A1266092011%2Cn%3A13447451%2Ck%3Amkv%20)'. If you usually avoid taking your devices on vacation, I'd suggest grabbing a TV Box - [some of them](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008NO9RRM) are smaller than a pack of cigarettes, weigh less than 200 grams, cost less than $50, and ship with a remote control.

While I'm sure some sort of a universal remote could solve your issue, I highly doubt it would be as convenient as a separate device.

Comment: Or a device for playing wirelessly from a phone or tablet. eg Miracast, or Chromecast.

Comment: @vclaw This would also require carrying a separate box (far from all TVs support it) and wireless is always less reliable. I'd stick with a TV Box.

Comment: A Chromecast is pretty small, so not much to carry, it doesn't need a separate remote control. Depends on what sort of media you are playing - if its already stored on your phone, I think its simplest to play it from there.

Comment: @vclaw does Chromecast work if no Wi-Fi is available? E.g. can you set-up an ad-hoc network with just your phone and use it to stream content?

Comment: @JonathanReez yes, with tethering, but you need two devices.

Comment: @J.Constantine IMO not a very good solution for a cruise then

Comment: @JonathanReez why not? If you're two people with two phones or have a phone and a laptop, you're set. And if not, you find a different solution.